# Is possible to rename a luks slot?

Tags: luks

I have successfully removed the second slot(is 1, because luks slots start from 0)
from an encrypted device.

```bsh
$> echo mypass | cryptsetup luksKillSlot /dev/loop0 1
```

Now I have this situation

```bsh
$> cryptsetup luksDump /dev/loop0 |grep -iw luks2
```

```
  0: luks2
  2: luks2
```

The question is: is possible to rename 2: luks2 to 1: luks2 to get something like this?

```bsh
$> cryptsetup luksDump /dev/loop0 |grep -iw luks2
```

```
  0: luks2
  1: luks2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2` is key slot ID so it's not possible to "rename" it -- the second key is in slot 2 and the slot 1 is still there just empty (because you wiped it with kill slot). (You always have 8 slots (with LUKS 1, with LUKS 2 you can have up to 32 slots), some of them unused and some of them with keys, `luksKillSlot` just wipes the content of the slot, it doesn't remove the slot.)

It's not possible to simply move the key from one key slot to the other so if you really want to change this, you need to add a new key to the key slot number 1 with `cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-slot 1` (and with the same passphrase you use for the slot 2) and then remove the key slot number 2.

Note: working with key slots can be dangerous, if you make a mistake you can easily destroy the last key slot, so I would avoid doing that just to make the `luksDump` output "prettier", but if you want to do that, you can, but you should make a header backup first.